# Getting a PropertyGrid scrollbar to default back to the top when an item is selected

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, propertygrid

In my C# .Net program, a list of items is presented on the left and a PropertyGrid is displayed on the right with information on the item selected. When I move the scrollbar for the PropertyGrid then select another item from the list, the scrollbar stays where it was previously. I want to be able to reset the scrollbar to the top every time a new item is selected.

I've been able to see where the .value of the scrollbar is stored, but I can't access it (System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PropertyGridView.ScrollBar). Is there any way I can get access to these values to change them?

This was the only thing I found in other questions, but I'm not sure how I could adapt this solution to my problem:
[How can I catch scroll events in windows forms PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596100/how-can-i-catch-scroll-events-in-windows-forms-propertygrid?answertab=active#tab-top)

**EDIT: The question I linked to is how I eventually solved the problem. I used Reflection to get the internal scrollBar control and SetScrollOffset method, then used those to set the scrollbar value to 0 when the item on the left was changed.**

Comment: Perhaps specify which type of Control (like a ListBox) you specified on the left to clarify your question.

Comment: It's an Infragistics UltraGrid. Updated the original question with the Infragistics tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the SelectedObject of the PropertyGrid to null before setting it to the new value.